# Must be str, not int

Tags: python

Keep gettting this error:in pos sqlcuery="insert into position, 'position', values('"+position+"')"
TypeError: must be str, not int

```
position= x + int(w/2)
        if position > 320:
             sqlcuery = pos(position)
             insertrec.db.execute(sqlcuery)
             db.commit()
             print(klar)
             db.close()

def pos(position):
    sqlcuery="insert into position ('position'), values('"+position+"')"
    return sqlcuery
```

Keep gettting this error, even if I change to str() or using ","

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include the full traceback error.

Comment: `position` is an integer value. Have you tried to convert `position` to a string in the formatting of `sqlcuery`?

Comment: Note that you should't be concatenating values into SQL strings to begin with. Use the parameterised query API of whatever database adapter you have. Usually it'd look something like `insertrec.db.execute('INSERT INTO position (position) VALUES (%s)', (position,))`.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I'd recommend using an f-string. These allow you to input variables of any type within your code without too much issue. Wrap your variables in {}, like I've shown below.

```
sqlcuery=f"insert into position {position}"
```

Answer (score 1):

Can I suggest that you use an f-string if you're on a version of python that supports them.

```
sqlcuery=f"insert into position ('position'), values('{position}')"
```

Comment: this gives an error since the variable `postions` doesn't exist

Comment: sorry, typo by me, it should be `positions` - let me correct

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
"insert into position ('position'), values('"+str(position)+"')"
```

To transform the integer or float to a string.

You can do this more elegantly with a f-string:

```
f"insert into position ('position'), values('{position}')"
```

Comment: no need for the `str` inside an f-string

Comment: oops, that was a sloppy copy+paste. edited my answer.